# Mots français ayant fait un passage par l'anglais avant de revenir

Tags: anglais, histoire, anglicismes

Je recherche une liste bien remplie, à défaut d'exhaustive, de mots français qui proviennent de mots anglais, eux-mêmes provenant de mots français.

Par exemple, on peut penser à un *mél* (ou *e-mail*) provenant de l'anglais *e-mail*, lui même provenant du vieux français *mail* qui désigne la poste. J'aimerais avoir une liste de ce genre de mots.

Comment: Exhaustif, t'as raison il y en a trop, les plus connus : flirter, tunnel, mel (mail qui vient de malle et pas de mail), bar, car, hobby, fax, tennis ticket, des tas de gens ont déjà dû chercher à faire une liste... [ici](http://wordn3rd.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/loeuf-et-la-poule/). Et si on commençait un community wiki ici même ?

Comment: En effet un cw me semble approprié et le lien fournit permet de commencer avec quelques exemples supplémentaires.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Bar

Les anglais ont pris l'ancien français *barre* au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle sous la forme *bar*. Le mot y a d'abord désigné une barrière, puis le comptoir de taverne qui servait de séparation entre l'endroit où on servait les boissons de celui où on les  buvait. Au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle  le mot a désigné la taverne elle-même et il est revenu en  France au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner le meuble sur lequel on pose les boissons alcoolisées et le lieu où on les vend et on peut les consommer.

#### Brunette

Au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle une brunette désignait une étoffe très fine de couleur presque noire. Il a ensuite désigné une petite fille dont les cheveux tiraient vers le brun et le mot a disparu du français dans ce sens là pour y revenir via l'influence de l'anglais qui l'avait emprunté au français (XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle) pour désigner une jeune femme brune.

#### Budget

Une *bougette* en moyen français était une bourse en cuir dans laquelle on mettait de l'argent. Les anglais ont pris le mot au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle (diverses graphies pour arriver à l'orthographe actuelle de *budget*), d'abord avec le même sens, puis en désignant le contenu de la bourse pour arriver au sens actuel d'ensemble des entrées et sorties d'argent.

Le français a repris le mot *budget* à l'anglais au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, il a d'abord désigné le système anglais de recettes et de dépenses qui était unique en son genre à l'époque, le mot fut appliqué aux finances françaises au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

#### Festival

L'anglais emprunta l'adjectif *festivel* ou *festival* au vieux français et en fit au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle un nom pour désigner un jour de fête puis au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle une série de manifestations musicales, et c'est à ce moment là qu'il est revenu sous forme de nom, et avec ce sens de manifestation artistique, en français.

#### Flirter

L'idée populaire (répandue par le *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue française* de  Bloch et  Wartburg) comme quoi l'anglais *to flirt* viendrait du français « conter fleurette » est rejetée par certains lexicographes  (dont Alain Rey & co) parce que *conter fleurette* ne date que du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, c'est à dire un siècle après que le mot anglais *to flirt* ait pris son sens actuel.

L'anglais *to flirt* (origine onomatopéique), qui était utilisé depuis le XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle avec le sens de « agiter, remuer » a pris le sens de « faire la cour » au  XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle siècle. Il est passé en français  (*flirter* ou *fleureter*)  au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

#### Interview

*Interview* est emprunté au français *entrevue* (participe passé féminin singulier d'entrevoir) dont il reprend le plus souvent le genre (« Une interview »).

#### Label

Le mot est entré en Angleterre au XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle avec le sens de « ruban, bande de tissu ». Il est revenu en France au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle à deux reprises. Une première fois dans les années 1930 avec le sens de « marque de qualité » et dans les années 1960 dans son sens informatique.

#### Magasin/magazine

De l'arabe *maḫzan* le mot *magasin* est arrivé en français au XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle avec le sens d'entrepôt. 
Les Anglais l'ont emprunté vers la fin du  XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner un endroit où on entrepose des marchandises, puis l'ont utilisé aussi pour désigner un livre dans lequel on classe des informations sur un sujet spécifique.

C'est au  XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle qu'il a été pour la première fois employé en Angleterre pour désigner une publication contenant des articles d'intérêt général et rédigés par des contributeurs différents.  Et vers la fin du  XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle il est revenu en France avec l'orthographe *magazine*, au début pour désigner des magazines anglais et ensuite tout type de publication périodique de ce genre.

#### Partenaire

Le vieux français *parçener*, cohéritier, a donné l'anglais *partner* qui est revenu sous la forme de *partenaire*.

#### Pedigree

*Pedigree* est une transcription phonétique du français *Pied de grue* (anciennement: *pié de grue*) qui décrivait de manière imagée la forme d'une arbre généalogique. La réforme de 1990 permet l'orthographe *pédigrée*.

#### Shopping

De l'anglais shopping, qui vient du nom *shop* qui vint lui-même de l'ancien français *eschoppe*.

#### Sport

De l’anglais *sport* tiré de l’ancien français *desport* (jeu, amusement), lui-même du latin *deportare*. [Source](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sport#.C3.89tymologie).

#### Tennis

*Tennis* est emprunté au français « tenez » (impératif de tenir) qui est l'exclamation du serveur dans le [jeu de paume](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_paume), jeu que les anglais ont importé au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle sous la forme de *tenetz* /*teneys* /*tenyse* puis *tennis* (XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle) et qui est revenu sous cette forme en France au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

#### Ticket

Autrefois, un *ticket*, en anglais, c'était une [étiquette](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etiquette#English) : un morceau de papier que l'on apposait à un objet. Le mot s'est généralisé à des morceaux de papier volants, d'où le sens moderne de *billet* qui est repassé en français.

#### Tunnel

Les Anglais ont emprunté le mot français *tonnelle* (du latin *tonna* "récipient", qui a donné aussi le gaulois *tůnna* "tonneau") dont on trouve la première occurrence en 1440 pour désigner un filet en forme de tube qui servait à attraper les perdrix. Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle il désignait un tube et c'est au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, alors que les travaux de génie civil se multiplient en Grande Bretagne avec la Révolution Industrielle, qu'il acquiert son sens actuel de passage souterrain.

C'est l'ingénieur franco britannique  [Brunel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Isambard_Brunel) qui a dirigé de grands travaux dans Londres au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, et en particulier le tunnel sous la Tamise, qui a permis le retour du mot en français avec sons sens actuel *tunnel* dans le vocabulaire français.

#### Vintage

Le mot d'ancien français *vendage* (vendange) est passé en Angleterre au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner la récolte du raisin. 
Vintage a commencé à désigner en anglais au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner le cru et au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle comme adjectif pour désigner quelque chose d'ancien. Il est revenu en France au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle avec ce dernier sens.

Answer (score 1):

Je rajouterais record, bifsteak (pour la premiere partie seulement buen sur), car (le vehicule), curfew (utilisé dans le milieu de la musique surtout)   (il y a souvent des doutes sur l'etymologie : francais de normandie, francais, latin, co-influences des 3)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi ***[poney](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poney)*** mais à moins d’établir une liste inédite ici, ce dont je ne me sens pas l’ambition, il existe le livre de Jean Tournier, *Les Mots anglais du français*, Paris, Belin, 1998, 620 p. (ISBN 9782701123042), Traitant des réemprunts mais du reste, je ne l’ai pas lu et ne saurais attester qu’il contienne ce que vous cherchiez :)

Comment: Je connais et ça ne traite pas des mots français qui ont fait un aller retour.

Answer (score 1):

**Toast**

*étymologie (TLFi)* : 1750 (Prévost, Manuel lexique, loc. cit.: Toast [...] Ce mot en lui-même signifie Rôtie, et vient de l'usage qu'ont les Anglois de mettre quelquefois du pain rôti dans leur vin pour boire les santés); 1825 toast (en France) (Brillat-Sav., Physiol. goût, p. 168 et p. 182). Empr. à l'angl.toast « rôtie, tranche de pain grillée que l'on trempe généralement dans une boisson » (ca 1430 ds NED) corresp. à l'a. fr. tostee de même sens (ca 1228 Jean Renart, Guillaume de Dole, éd. F. Lecoy, v. 493), et déverbal de to toast (v. toster étymol. B)

**Entrepreneur**

Il s'agit du  mot tel qu'utilisé surtout aux EUA et signifiant « individu investissant d'important moyens financiers dans de nouveaux ou même d'anciens domaines d'activité qui ont trait au  commerce, la finance, l'industrie, les transports, la recherche, et quelques autres » et que l'on a commencé à utiliser selon cette acception en France tout dernièrement.

Apparemment, celui-ci a été emprunté deux fois.

[étymologie](https://www.etymonline.com/word/entrepreneur) : 1828, "manager or promoter of a theatrical production," reborrowing of French entrepreneur "one who undertakes or manages," agent noun from Old French entreprendre "undertake" (see enterprise). The word first crossed the Channel late 15c. (Middle English entreprenour) but did not stay. Meaning "business manager" is from 1852. Related: Entrepreneurship.

Comment: _Toast_ +1. Même doublement si je me souviens bien c'est qu'il est aussi réemprunté pour le _toast_ signifiant lever son verre !